# ASP.NET MVC 4 - How to incorporate jQuery UI menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm looking to use the jQuery UI menu in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project but the jQuery UI menu is not included by default (or so I think). I've downloaded a folder from jQuery UI with just the menu but but I am not sure where to place the JavaScript file.

My question then is where do I place said file and is this the correct way go about adding the jQuery UI menu?

Comment: Add the css/js files wherever you want and then reference them in your page?

Comment: try updating jQuery UI in nuget package manager.

Comment: If you are using bundling, add it after the reference to jquery js. If not bundling, search for your jquery js file in the project and add jquery UI js file after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it as any other library include css files in ~/Content/css images in ~/Content/img
js files under Scripts folder. Add it to `<head>` of your page or you can create mvc Bundles and use `@Scripts.Render()` and `@Styles.Render()` , which is the correct way.

You can read more here :

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Or here is the simpler approach to get started , similar to users jQueryUI with just few components , like Menu in your case :

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_ui_mvc_intro.ashx